# Does Parallel.ForEach start threads if the source is empty?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am using a `Parallel.ForEach` in this way:

```
public void myMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> paramIeCollection)
{
    Parallel.Foreach(paramIeCollection,
          (iterator) =>
          {
              //Do something
          });
}
```

I am wondering if when `paramIeCollection` is empty, the `Parallel.ForEach` starts anyway and take threads from Thread Pool and consumes resources or if it first checks if there are items in the collection.

If it doesn't check, to avoid that, I am thinking in this code:

```
if(paramIeCollection.count > 0)
{
    //run Parallel.Foreach
}
```

So the question is, is it a good practice to check if the collection has items before calling `Parallel.ForEach` or if it isn't needed?

Comment: `the parallel.foreach starts anyway and take threads from thread pool` No. `it cecks if there are items before use resorces.` Yes.

Comment: `paramIeCollection.count` The other downside of this approach is twofold. a) It won't compile (you have some typos). b) Getting the `Count()` of some `IEnumerable`s (e.g. `IQueryable`) will have large performance consequences (e.g. it may hit the database again). _As such - just let `Parallel.ForEach` take care of it for you._

Comment: @Álvaro García Hi, its probably a good idea to mark this question as answer if it suits your purpose, as it will most propagate further up the list on a search

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The truth be known it does check. However if you go through the source there are a handful of other *checks and balances* it does before it figures it out.

If you have *processor instruction OCD*, a simple check beforehand like `if(list.count > 0)` will probably save you a bunch of IL. however in the real world it wont make much of a difference

[`System.Threading.Tasks` Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs.html)

For instance, for the simple `IEnumerable` overload, you can follow the source code through E.g

```
public static ParallelLoopResult ForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> body)
```

Calls [ForEachWorker](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,ecf3d8a35545d82b)

```
private static ParallelLoopResult ForEachWorker<TSource, TLocal>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
        Action<TSource> body,
        Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState> bodyWithState,
        Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState, long> bodyWithStateAndIndex,
        Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> bodyWithStateAndLocal,
        Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, long, TLocal, TLocal> bodyWithEverything,
        Func<TLocal> localInit, Action<TLocal> localFinally)
```

Calls inline

```
// This is an honest-to-goodness IEnumerable.  Wrap it in a Partitioner and defer to our
        // ForEach(Partitioner) logic.
return PartitionerForEachWorker<TSource, TLocal>(Partitioner.Create(source), parallelOptions, body, bodyWithState,
            bodyWithStateAndIndex, bodyWithStateAndLocal, bodyWithEverything, localInit, localFinally);
```

[PartitionerForEachWorker](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,38a83efeaf70c495)

```
// Main worker method for Parallel.ForEach() calls w/ Partitioners.
private static ParallelLoopResult PartitionerForEachWorker<TSource, TLocal>(
        Partitioner<TSource> source, // Might be OrderablePartitioner
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
        Action<TSource> simpleBody,
        Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState> bodyWithState,
        Action<TSource, ParallelLoopState, long> bodyWithStateAndIndex,
        Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, TLocal, TLocal> bodyWithStateAndLocal,
        Func<TSource, ParallelLoopState, long, TLocal, TLocal> bodyWithEverything,
        Func<TLocal> localInit,
        Action<TLocal> localFinally)
```

Which eventually does the check

```
while (myPartition.MoveNext())
```

Answer (score 4):

`Parallel.ForEach` will internally call `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` which will return `false` on an empty collection, so no work will be done.
While it t is faster to check directly whether the collection is empty, the difference is likely negligible.